# get google spreadsheet in json gives 404 Not found

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-docs-api, google-sheets-api

I tried all possible way on the internet to fetch my google spreadsheet as json

```
$.getJSON()
```

But I keep getting 404 Not found. On publish to web I get this  url: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vho9BS2YdCz3aKuLyV9m15stYhBu4G97ngzRasQsG1Y/pubhtml`.

To fetch json I tired all the combinations of url in this

```
url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vho9BS2YdCz3aKuLyV9m15stYhBu4G97ngzRasQsG1Y/od6/public/values?alt=json&callback=?";
$.getJSON(url, function(resp) {
    console.log(resp)
});
```

Not sure what else to do. Seems the od6/public/value format does not work fro me. Also in "publish to web", google seems to have removed the Cells and List option.

**Solution:**
I decided to use https://github.com/chriszarate/sheetrock. Did an awesome job!

Comment: Are you enable publish to the web option

Comment: API requests using the public visiblity for feeds on spreadsheets that are not "Published to the Web" yield an `HTTP 400 Bad Request response` with the message `The spreadsheet at this URL could not be found. Make sure that you have the right URL and that the owner of the spreadsheet hasn't deleted it.`

Comment: Before trying with jquery you should try with your browser. In this case it says the file does not exist. Wait. My mistake, I can read it in the first link you pasted.

Comment: Yes it is my own spreadsheet. You can try the public url too.

Comment: what steps did you follow to publish this spreadsheet on the web? What format did you pick to publish? I tried with one of [**my spreadsheets**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aj_MtsZiuNB1dFRzSFdtYWo3b1VEQ1JGWjhCamRvUGc#gid=0)  and after publishing I got an [**url similar to yours**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0Aj_MtsZiuNB1dFRzSFdtYWo3b1VEQ1JGWjhCamRvUGc&output=html) albeit no identical. Now I replaced my id in your [**json url**](https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0Aj_MtsZiuNB1dFRzSFdtYWo3b1VEQ1JGWjhCamRvUGc/od6/public/values?alt=json) and it works.

Comment: So my url get transformed to [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vho9BS2YdCz3aKuLyV9m15stYhBu4G97ngzRasQsG1Y/od6/public/values?alt=json&callback=jQuery111003001928748562932_1407001389322&_=1407001389323) when using jquery getJSON. Also I do not get any option for publish format. It just says start publishing.

Answer (score 0):

The url you are trying to reach is not returning the JSON.
It returns HTML, so the JQ function does not know what to do with the data it receives.